# search for a single type of text in a line

Tags: regex

I have a line:

`Allowed VLAN: 1(t), 30(t), 228(t), 296(t), 303(t), 387(t) 401(t),`

Can I write a regular expression to find 7 matches of a number, followed by `(t)` ?

My expression `(?mi)^\s+allowed\svlan:(\s\d+(?=\(t\)))` finds only 1 occurrence, and I want to find all the subsequent ones too.

Comment: What is the language / environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a positive lookahead : [`\d+(?=\(t\))`](https://regex101.com/r/C4R1JJ/1).

`\d+` looks for a digit 1 or more times

`(?=\(t\))` makes sure `(t)` follows your expression

Comment: Note that this doesn't actually assert that there are 7 occurrences.

Comment: By looking at OP's try, I figured he wanted all occurrences, not 7, he only precised 7 matches to say he wanted them all. Could be wrong, though.

Comment: Yes, your answer can do that, but then the OP is worded badly.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the following pattern:

```
(?:\d+\(t\).*){7,}
```

Here is a demo in Java:

### Demo